# print view and actual print stopped working correctly, CSS and HTML in angularJS app

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So last week I deployed an app, after everything was working correctly, basically you get a bunch of data from the API and these data gets formatted into tables and there is a specific print css to print it nicely.

Everything was working correctly, even after some days when I checked some stuff, then today I got notified that the print view is completly messed up, went to check and it was messed up.

No changes to the css code or even the code on the page in question have been made.  Basically the problem is that in the normal browser view everything works perfectly, even if you EMULATE the print view, it gets displayed correctly, but the problems start when you actually print it! (or pop the chrome printing preview), all the text is too big and overlapped, a single page because of that gets printed on 2 pages.

I check and rechecked and the code is identical from when it worked.
I tried printing with latest version of Chrome and Firefox, both print on 2 pages and zoomed content.

I used Bootstrap v3.3.7 and the app is made with angularJS.

I tried puttin in the `@media print` stuff like `* {transition: none !important}`

that I find on other topic here on stackoverflow, but nothing works.

The problem aren't only font sizes, I'm currently changing all the font size in the print @media from px to pt, but the divs are also zoomed, I need to change some classes from col-xs-6 to col-xs-4 to have the correct placement and size of the divs.

The only thing that I noticed gives me the CORRECT print as It was over a week ago, is setting on the print settings in Chrome, SCALE = 44 or less, under 44 the content is small but everything is correct, the placement of the text and the divs, maybe this tells you something I dont know.

So sorry for the wall of text, I don't even know what code to post honestly, as everything was working before and the css page is huge, I'm grasping for ideas on what could have happened.

EDIT: SOLUTION
solved by simply changing all the print rules from pixels to points so it prints correctly on every browser, sadly didn't figure out the reason why it stopped working out of the blue

Comment: make sure you're printing with the browser view at 100%?

Comment: you mean ctrl+wheel up for the 100%? if it's that, it's 100%, and this happens on every pc I tried and on different browsers

Comment: Do you have a url we can check out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to added your .ts file to **inline .css** like this

```
popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><style>css here...</style> QR Code </head><body  onload="window.print()">' + innerContents + '</html>');
```